# JQuery Mobile - event that is called when a select box is closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What is a possible event I can use to bind whenever the select box is closed by the x button?

```
        <select name="select-choice-6" id="select-choice-6" class="select" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
            <option>Search by:</option>
            <option value="id">Student ID</option>
            <option value="permit">Permit</option>
            <option value="license">License Plate</option>
            <option value="first">First Name</option>
            <option value="last">Last Name</option>
            <option value="lot">Lot Code</option>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on( "popupafterclose", ".ui-popup-container", function() {
                alert("hi");
            });
            $("#select-choice-6").trigger("popupafterclose");
```

Comment: if it's a popup, use `popupafterclose`. Which jQM version are you using?

Comment: 1.3.1, that is the version I am using. Edit: popupafterclose does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pagehide` event, as `dialog` accepts same events of `page` in jQuery Mobile

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/M28Bc/)**

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '[data-role=dialog]', function () {
 // Your code here
});
```

Comment: @JimRilye now it's a `dialog`. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Omar, thank you it works now. But may I ask since I am new to JQM, how or where might you find that the method for this is 'pagehide' and that the pop up is a dialog box instead of something else? I would love if you could point me in a general direction

Comment: @JimRilye You're welcome :) please read the first paragraph in this link http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/ _"Any page can be presented as a modal dialog by adding the `data-rel="dialog"`"_ This means that dialogs are being treated as a div with `data-role=page`. Read about popups here http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/ if you have any question, email me omarmt [at] gmail.com

Comment: @Omar, thanks I'll be sure to look at the links and email you if need be

Answer (score 3):

If your select has the ID foo, jQuery Mobile creates a popup with the name foo-listbox-popup. You can then listen for the popupafterclose event like this:

```
$(document).on('popupafterclose', '#foo-listbox-popup', function () {
    alert('closed');
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9xjvanq/) using JQM 1.3.0b1 (I am using this solution with JQM 1.4.5).